# can we serialize a class with out any meber

Tags: java, serialization

Can we serialize a class with out any members? My class is as below

```
Class test
{
  public void method1(){ 
    //No code
  }
  public void method2(){
    //No code 
  }
}
```

If yes then what will be the size of the selialized object file?

Comment: yes, in your case no.

Comment: How do you plan to serialize it? ObjectOutputStream? Then your class has to implement ``Serializable``. If so: why don't you try it and take a look at the number of bytes?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. But you need to write

`Class test implements java.io.Serializable`

to kick off Java's (rather clever) serialisation mechanism, and really you ought to provide a value of `serialVersionUID` as a static field in the class:

`static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`

to avoid relying on the one that a Java compiler generators (which could vary from compiler implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you have to declare that your class implements the java.io.Serializable interface.

Here is a complete example in one file **Main.java** :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class ObjectSize {

    public static byte[] toByteArray(Object object) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(object);
        return bos.toByteArray();
      } 


    public static int getSize(Object obj) throws IOException{

        return toByteArray(obj).length;

    }

}


class Pojo1 implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int x = 0 ;
}

class Pojo2 implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int x, y = 0 ;
}

class Pojo3 implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int x, y , z = 0 ;
}

class Test implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void method1(){}
    public void method2(){}
}


class Test2 implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void method1(){}
    public void method2(){}
    public void method3(){}
    public int method4(){return 100;}
    public int method5(){return 0;}
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try {

            out.println("Pojo with 1  field  size = "+ObjectSize.getSize(new Pojo1()));
            out.println("Pojo with 2  fields size = "+ObjectSize.getSize(new Pojo2()));
            out.println("Pojo with 3  fields size = "+ObjectSize.getSize(new Pojo3()));
            out.println("Pojo with no fields = "+ObjectSize.getSize(new Test()));
            out.println("Pojo with no fields and a method which returns an int size = "+ObjectSize.getSize(new Test2()));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Results :**
Pojo with 1  field  size = 34

Pojo with 2  fields size = 42

Pojo with 3  fields size = 50

Pojo with no fields = 25

Pojo with no fields and a method which returns an int size = 26